# Average time complexity of simple recursive algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I need to calculate average time complexity of the following pseudocode. It's not a homework, I am preparing for an exam, and it's going quite poorly so far. So all kind of tips are welcomed.

[image]

I am not sure if I should define recursive relation that would look +- like that:

$$\begin{cases} T(0) = 1 \\ T(n) = b_{n}T(n-1) + c_{n}\end{cases}$$

and then solve it to get my time complexity, or just somehow calculate time complexity straight away.

Some initial ideas: propability $p_{1}$ that $n > 0$ is $\frac{1}{n}$, therefore propability that instruction in 13rd row will execute is $p_{2} = 1 - p_{1} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$

and 10th's row instruction is executed $n$ times.

So perhaps average time complexity should approximately look like that?

$$T_{avg}(n) = \underbrace{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}(n-1)}_{\text{instruction 10}} + \overbrace{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(1 - \frac{1}{n})1}^{\text{instruction 13}}$$

and then of course calculate it futher? How close am I?

I am mostly confused about lines $6, 7$ that imply recursion and how to tie up everything together.

All tips are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: An interesting exercise. What is the source?

Comment: It's from our Algorithms and Data Structures' first year course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work through the case in which `m` is fixed. If $n = 0$ there is just one `print`, if $n > 0$ you see there are $2 n$ calls to `F2(m)` and $n + 1$ calls to `print`. But $m$ isn't fixed, you have to average over it's possible values ($0 \le m \le n - 1$).

Call $T_n$ the number of times (on average) that `print` is called for $n$. Then:

$\begin{align*}
T_n
  = \begin{cases}
       1 & n = 0 \\
       n + 1 + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{0 \le m \le n - 1} T_m & n > 0
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}$

Not exactly bog-standard...

Dig in with generating functions: Define $g(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} T_n z^n$, multiply the $n > 0$ branch by $n z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 1$. Then identify some sums:

$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \ge 1} n T_n z^n
  &= \sum_{n \ge 1} n (n + 1) z^n + 2 \sum_{n \ge 1} z^n \sum_{0 \le m \le n - 1} T_m \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} n T_n z^n
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} n (n + 1) z^n + 2 z \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \sum_{0 \le m \le n} T_m \\
z g'(z)
  &= z \frac{d^2}{d z^2} \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n + 2 z \frac{g(z)}{1 - z} \\
z g'(z)
  &= z \frac{2}{(1 - z)^3} + 2 z \frac{g(z)}{1 - z} \\
\end{align*}$

Here we added some terms that are zero for symmetry, and adjusted indices in the last sum.
Now solve the differential equation. We know $g(0) = T_0 = 1$:

$\begin{align*}
g(z)
  &= \frac{c - 2 \ln(1 - z)}{(1 - z)^2} \\
  &= \frac{1 - 2 \ln(1 - z)}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align*}$

We want the coefficient of $z^n$:

$\begin{align*}
T_n
  &= [z^n] g(z) \\
  &= 2 (-1)^n \binom{-2}{n} - [z^n] \frac{\ln(1 - z)}{(1 - z)^2} \\
  &= 2 \binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} - [z^n] \frac{\ln(1 - z)}{(1 - z)^2} \\
  &= 2 \frac{n + 1}{1} - [z^n] \frac{\ln(1 - z)}{(1 - z)^2} \\
  &= 2 n + 2 - 2 [z^n] \frac{\ln(1 - z)}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align*}$

The last term is somewhat troublesome. But we know that $\frac{A(z)}{1 - z}$ is the generating function of partial sums, doing it twice here:

$\begin{align*}
[z^n] \frac{- \ln(1 - z)}{(1 - z)^2}
  &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \sum_{1 \le j \le k} \frac{1}{j} \\
  &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{n - k + 1}{k} \\
  &= (n + 1) H_n - n
\end{align*}$

We use harmonic numbers $H_n = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k}$ here.

Pulling all together:

$\begin{align*}
T_n
  &= 2 n + 2 + 2 (n + 1) H_n - 2 n \\
  &= (n + 1) H_n + 2
\end{align*}$

Comment: Thank you for posting this. This is a little bit out of my knowledge, though. I know differential equations, but we were not introduced to them at all during our Algorithms classes. I will be definitely coming back here to understand this as soon as I can.